# Get detected device USB port from TJvHidDeviceController in delphi?

Tags: delphi, usb, port

I'm using TJvHidDeviceController to detect my electronic device connection into USB port. After detection I need to know its port name to use in TComPort object. (It is a simple Caller ID device).
How can I know the detected device's port name(I want to know com port. for example COM1 or COM2. Witch com it is (my device connected to it)). 
I searched a lot but can not find anything. Thanks

My code :

```
s := HidDev.ProductName;
if(s.IndexOf('caller') > 0)then
  // Need port here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of search I found the solution.

```
ComPort.Port := HidDev.PnPInfo.DevicePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what TJvHidDeviceController is, but the string you would use to access a USB device as a COM port, has the form like this (where X's are hexadecimal digits):

```
USB#VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX#xxxxxx#{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
```

Comment: I want to know com port. for example COM1 or COM2. Witch com it is (my device connected to it)

Comment: Exactly, instead of `COM1` or `COM2` use a `USB...` string of the format above